# How to print (to paper) a nicely formatted page with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, printing, xps, formatted

I need to print a nicely formatted (bold and 3 different fonts) page to a remote printer queue with Powershell. Unfortunately I did not find a usable solution for printing. Searching Google, most answers are: create a .html file and print this file with Internet Explorer. My Powershell script runs from an Windows service (a backup software). It seams that Internet Explorer can't be launched from an service, so I cant print the .html file. Powershell is the only scripting language available in this context. Now I search for an solution to print an .html or .xps file from Powershell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Share some code please.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

Have your service...

1 - Try creating a normal scheduled task that looks to a folder where you output the HTML file, and print via a normal PoSH script via the scheduled task.

2 - Create / Register a WMI event that that monitors a folder where you plan to output the html and print similarly via a normal PoSH script